# Make a wordpress site similar to Hot Or Not - Image rating system

Tags: plugins, images, rating

I'm wondering how I would go about implementing some kind of image voting system to wordpress. I've had a brief look at plugins but none are particularly great.

I would also like users to be able to upload photos? I'm not great with wordpress so any advice would be great. I'm literally open to anything here.

I was also thinking of adding in buddypress to give some kind of community behind it all.

Any advice welcome at all. More the merrier in fact!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps WordPress database schema is not so good for an implementation like this one, there's a couple of ways of how to do it.

You could set a [`rating` post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) that is actually a reference with [attachmed images](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) and some information for people to rate. So, every time a [`is_user_logged_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) user rates any post of this post type, you'll probably want to [set the post as rated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) by this user (so he won't rate it again) on a reference for him in `wp_usermeta`, and also [increase a `rating_count`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) on `wp_postmeta`.

Well, this is just to start.